# Laravel Form::text generates no exact code

Tags: php, laravel-5.1

Where to repair a laravel code

```
{!! Form::text('name', null, 
    array('required', 
    'id'=>'name', 
    'class'=>'form-control',
    'required'=>'required',
    'placeholder'=>'Your name')) !!}
```

That it would generates

```
<input required="required" id="name" class="form-control" required="required" placeholder="Your name" name="name" type="text" />
```

instead of

```
<input required="required" id="name" class="form-control" required="required" placeholder="Your name" name="name" type="text">
```

i.e it would end with ".. />" instead of ".. >"
? Does somebody know?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Check the line [258](https://github.com/LaravelCollective/html/blob/5.1/src/FormBuilder.php#L258) of the input function of `FormBuilder` class where it should have been located as `vendor/laravelcollective/html/src/FormBuilder.php` :

You should change it to

```
return '<input' . $this->html->attributes($options) . '/>';
```

But instead of modifying the vendor file, you should better extend the HTML class then modify the `FormBuilder` class and register the modified one within your `config/app.php` file.

Answer (score 1):

There's nothing wrong for having a / at the ending. That's actually how it should. That is an html input. before input would be declare like

```
<input blah blah blah></input>
```

so `<input blah blah />` is actually the shorthand of that . . I think